# How to validate XML with multiple encodings (or at least multiple languages)

Tags: xml, validation, encoding, utf-8, xsd

I have an XSD and an XML sample document from a company.  However, when I try to validate the XML against the XSD it fails with:

> Error: Premature end of data in tag SomeTag line 2

There's no obvious cause for the failure, and when I remove the foreign characters from the document it validates.

I'd like to make this sample XML validate-able, but with the fewest modifications possible (ie. I'd prefer to not just delete the foreign characters outright).  I know I can't add a second encoding to the document, but as I understand it its existing encoding (`utf-8`) should be able to handle Japanese characters ... if they're encoded in UTF (which, evidently from the failure, they are not).

So my question is, is there any way I can open this document in some (ideally OSS) program and then save it with UTF-8 encodings so that the Japanese characters don't break the validation?  If not, is there any other way I can make the document validate-able short of deleting every foreign character in it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can use any plain-text editor that can handle encodings. Ideally, you edit XML documents with a dedicated XML editor, but this particular case might be difficult if the document lies about its encoding.

After opening the document, if the Japanese characters don't look right, you need to change the way how the editor interprets the characters (doesn't change the file).
For example, in [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), there is a menu command called "Reopen with Encoding", which offers a long list of common encodings.
Select one that seems likely, and check the Japanese characters again.
Keep trying until they look right.

Then use a command like "Save with Encoding" and choose UTF-8.
This last command will change how the file is saved on disk.